# Hellang ProblemDetails hides real exception when 500 http ASP.NET CORE 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im using in my ASP.NET CORE C# API REST the nuget package Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails to return a ProblemDetails json object when I have a 404 and a 500. I like it but a have a problem and I dont know if is my blame.

Every time a exception is launched the result in my insight is a exception like this:

*System.InvalidOperationException*

*Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.StatusCodeProblemDetails cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.*

*An error occurred while trying to create an XmlSerializer for the type 'Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.StatusCodeProblemDetails'.*

This exception hides the real exception and I cant see it...

Im using it in a very simple way:

```
            services
                 .AddProblemDetails(setup =>
                 {
                     setup.IncludeExceptionDetails = _ =>
                         Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Local";
                 });
```

```
configureHost(app)
               .UseAuthentication()
               .UseProblemDetails()
               .UseMvc(routes =>
               {
                   routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "swagger",
                       template: "{controller=News}/{action=Swagger}");
               });
```

any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: where are your mappings?

Comment: In a extension method than is loaded later in the service collection. Do you think that the problem is the order of load between problemdetails config and mappings config?

Comment: In case if you want to step away from raising exceptions and mapping to `IActionResult`, you can use [DomainResult](https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult) NuGet package